# What aspects of Microsoft's UProve technology is patented by others?

Tags: software, opensource, encryption

Microsoft published their UProve technology to an open source license; however they mention that they can't guarantee that the technology does not infringe on other patents not covered by Microsoft.

What known patents can cause an issue for implementors of UProve technology?

Does it matter if UProve is configured to exclusively rely on "Subgroups" versus the patent minefield of ECC?

Comment: General discussion of Microsoft and/or open-source is probably off topic here. If you can edit your question to be more clear including patent number(s), it may help.

Comment: @RonJ.  I am only asking because the last patent Q I asked on Sec.SE was migrated here  http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3825/3814

Comment: A disclaimer that says "we are giving you X rights for free to use what we own but can't guarantee that using it won't infringe something we don't own" seems like a very sensible thing whether or not they have something specific in mind.

Comment: @RonJ -- if you have specific patents and subject matter in mind, then list the patent and the concern and ask for examples of prior art -- http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic